# Where are the headers of the C++ standard library

Tags: c++, linux, stl, header-files, std

I wonder where on my file system I find the headers of the C++ Standard library.  In particular I am looking for the definition of the vector template.  I searched in /usr/include/ and various subdirectories.  I also tried 'locate vector.h' which brought up many implementations of vectors, but not the standard one.  What am I missing?  (The distribution is Gentoo)

Background: I'm profiling a library that iterates over vector's most of the time and gprof shows that most of the time is spent in

```
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_insert_aux(
  __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<
      int, std::allocator<int> > >, int const&)
```

Probably this is what happens internally on a std::vector::push_back, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you searching for `vector` in the ***C*** includes?

Comment: All the preprocessing is handled by `cpp` so, why not to ask it?: `cpp -v`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

GCC typically has the standard C++ headers installed in `/usr/include/c++/<version>/`. You can run `gcc -v` to find out which version you have installed.

At least in my version, there is no `vector.h`; the public header is just `vector` (with no extension), and most of the implementation is in `bits/stl_vector.h`.

That's the case on my Ubuntu distribution; your distribution may differ.

Comment: Thanks, the missing .h ws the essential hint.  On Gentoo it's in /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.5.3/include/g++-v4/vector

Answer (score 13):

Running `g++ -v -v -v` outputs lots of things, including all the include directories searched. `vector` is in one of those.

Comment: `g++ -v` was all that was needed on MacOSX to give me the InstalledDir

Answer (score 3):

On my Debian Stable system `vector` is here:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.4/vector
```

Comment: Is it vector.h ?  Which package provides it? gcc?

Answer (score 2):

On a "plain" ubuntu install you have to install

`libstdc++-`*version*`-dev`

to get the header files.

then cheking the installed files you'll get the path !

Answer (score 2):

The file location is actually compiler-dependent.

You can use the bash tool "locate" to search for any of the files that you know are in the library. eg. "locate stl_multimap.h" for me yields:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_multimap.h
/usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_multimap.h
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_multimap.h
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_multimap.h
/usr/lib/gcc-snapshot/include/c++/9/bits/stl_multimap.h
```

Once you have a look at the directories it should become pretty obvious where everything else is too.

In each of those locations I'll find the different compiler versions of the file. For my computer, all the gcc 7.* files are in my `/usr/include/c++/7` directory.

If for some horrible reason you use Windows, I'm sure that you'll be able to find an equivalent command with Powershell.

Comment: On MacOSX13 I have to drop the `.h`  and use `locate iostream | grep Library` to find the correct location, which for me seems to be `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream`

Comment: Update: Using R. Martinho Fernades's suggestion below, the comand `g++ -v` show me the actual correct location being used by clang, namely:
`InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin` from which one can deduce and find the include location to be:
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream`

Answer (score 0):

In many IDE (e.g. NetBeans) you may use `Ctrl+Click` to className to go to definition