# Why are the headers not found in the Xilinx SDK?

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse-cdt, xilinx, zynq-ultrascale+

I am following the course "[Introduction to Deep Learning with Xilinx SoCs Technical Training Course](https://www.hackster.io/workshops/ultra96-ai-course)" for the Ultra96v2 board and reached Lab No. 5.

I am able to follow along until I am supposed to build the project in the SDK.
It fails and tells me errors like these:

```
15:49:06 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project mnist_file_io ****
make all 
Building file: ../src/mnist_file_io.cc
Invoking: ARM v8 Linux g++ compiler
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -Wall -O0 -g3 -I/media/user/6b04b610-ff80-4702-a575-b0b1a78fbafb/training/AvnetTTC/DPU/U96AI_student_20200115/U96AI/2018_3/work/lab5/workspace/ExtraIncludes -I/usr/include -c -fmessage-length=0 -MT"src/mnist_file_io.o" --sysroot=YSROOT -MMD -MP -MF"src/mnist_file_io.d" -MT"src/mnist_file_io.o" -o "src/mnist_file_io.o" "../src/mnist_file_io.cc"
In file included from ../src/mnist_file_io.cc:9:0:
/tools/Xilinx/SDK/2018.3/gnu/aarch64/lin/aarch64-linux/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/c++/7.3.1/cmath:45:15: fatal error: math.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <math.h>
               ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
src/subdir.mk:21: recipe for target 'src/mnist_file_io.o' failed
make: *** [src/mnist_file_io.o] Error 1
```

It doesnt find the header file, although it is included in the paths which were provided by the tutorial as well as by me. Actually, two additional files haven't been found:

- `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`
- `#include <dnndk/dnndk.h>`

I was able to include them by picking them by hand from the directories where they were in and adding them to an extra directory in which the Xilinx SDK should search for headers.
But this brings up the question: Why aren't they found in the first place? After correct installation and following the instructions in the above mentioned tutorial, shouldn't I be all set up to just build it?

Actually, by using the installer on the Xilinx Download website (`Xilinx_SDK_2018.3_1207_2324_Lin64.bin`), the SDK didn't start because there were some files missing for the SDK program (eclipse and some other stuff). So it just started once I copied those files from the other installation (Vivado, etc.). Isn't this also supposed to work just out of the box? Reinstalling, etc. didn't work unfortunately.

**So I guess one question that crystallizes here is**: Is there a possibility to give Eclipse/Xilinx SDK a path to a directory for all required standard header files and it searches in them? Because in some standard headers, they include other headers, which in turn aren't found by the Xilinx SDK. And will that fix my issues?

Funnily enough, when I use the Ctrl+Click action to jump from header to header, all headers are found and it's no problem. It's only in the build process where embedded further headers aren't found anymore. Also, when I change the `#include_next` to `#include`, the whole thing starts working again. The same with changing `#include <header>` to `#include "header.h"`. Then it works. But that can't be the solution, changing every header that throws an error, since it was generated like this for a reason, right?

This is really annoying and disrupts any workflow.
Is there someone who had this problem as well and may help me?
I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** and the Ultra96v2 board.

---

### Update

What I've investigated so far with no avail:

1. https://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless-connectivity/wi-fi-group/wifi/f/wi-fi-forum/993711/cc3235sf-why-is-ccs-eclipse-unable-to-see-the-c-standard-header-files
2. [Eclipse can't find header file, even though include paths are set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45619736/eclipse-cant-find-header-file-even-though-include-paths-are-set)
3. [Where are the headers of the C++ standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457670/where-are-the-headers-of-the-c-standard-library)
4. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1088833/

I have included the path for my C++ gcc standard library as a path in which Eclipse/the Xilinx IDE is supposed to search for headers, but the headers inside the files aren't being found.

---

### Update 2

Here you can see where the problem starts. It's really weird, since everything is auto-generated and thus should just work, especially since those are predefined headers and sources, which haven't been altered by me.

[image: Problem origin]

Here, you can see that I included the usual standard header location in the inclusion paths, so the files in question should be found.

[image: Standard headers included as path]

Comment: where were those files (you said you found them and copied them). You need to tell your project that you want to include those directories into your project. Check the `-I` flags of your compiler call. There is one specified to "ExtraIncludes" but I doubt that everything you need is in there. Additionally it seems that your sysroot is not properly set: `--sysroot=YSROOT`. I assume your problem lies there

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The ExtraIncludes doesn't include everything I need, I now copied the content of that folder into /usr/include, which lets the program find those files. However, the other files were not found even though I specifically declared the path to the files, and they also were inside the directory. So they exist and I show Eclipse where to find them, but it didn't find them.

Comment: I think you shouldn't copy around header files. Even if you get it running, you end up with a "difficult-to-reproduce" build-system. For the very first start I recommend to get a "Hello World" compiled by setting up your project accordingly. Therefor that you are crosscompiling, please do have a look into its pitfalls (you are using your build-systems `/usr/include` and your `--sysroot` seems wrongly configured ... both sounds fishy to me). When your hello-world compiles, try to add a library by adding it to your projects `-I` and `-L` compiler-flags

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it turned out that the sysroot was wrongly configured.